# How to find out IP address of a given push event in Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, audit

It's quite easy to impersonate another user in Gitlab. See [this topic](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/impersonating-another-user-on-push-how-to-block-it/734?u=wheleph) for more details.

It's possible to find out which user performed a push by examining "Activity" log of a repository. But for audit purposes I'd also like to know the IP address from which the push was done. Is it possible in Gitlab CE/EE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pushes done through HTTP(S)**

You can examine access logs of nginx (`nginx/gitlab_access.log`):

> 192.168.21.150 - johndoe [19/Dec/2016:08:05:58 +0100] "POST /TEST/test.git/git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 52 "-" "git/2.9.2.windows.1

**Pushes done through SSH**

You can examine gitlab-shell logs (`gitlab-shell/gitlab-shell.log`). That way you can find the time of a push:

> I, [2016-12-19T07:34:08.173561 #3560]  INFO -- : gitlab-shell: executing git command  for user with key key-417.

Then you can examine standard SSH logs to find the IP address: `/var/log/auth.log` or `/var/log/secure`:

> Dec 19 07:34:08 gitlab-hostname sshd[3563]: Accepted publickey for git from 192.168.21.151 port 40864 ssh2: RSA 32:ea:2d:e2:47:ac:fc:50:84:16:e2:16:57:b0:5c:2d

Comment: what about force push？

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find out the ip address from the production.log file.

Comment: I see only 127.0.0.1 in production.log. Probably those are coming from gitlab-shell and nginx that are on the same machine