# How to log all users' git command(pull/clone/push...) in Gitlab server?

Tags: git, gitlab

I want to statistic all command sent to gitlab server to get these info, **including time、duration、ip、 command(pull/clone/push)、repository**. I have already tried two methods, but not succeed:

1. access log

   gitlab's own log system has multiple log files, but none can log all git     command.
   For example, production.log can log all git command over http but not ssh.
2. hook

   git push can call hook function, but pull/clone can't

What else can I do?

Answer (score 3):

As stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41231761/1823672) **HTTP** and **SSH** requests are logged in different files:

- **HTTP**: `nginx/gitlab_access.log`
- **SSH**: [`gitlab-shell.log`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/logs.html#production-log)

Therefore  you will need to  parse your info from more than one file.

*Note that `gitlab-shell.log` does not show every information you want. So to have gitlab-shell logging more users' information, you have to patch **GitLab**, both the **Rails** application and the **SSH Shell** parts.*

To make the patchings you can follow these [instructions from the gitlab-auditor](https://github.com/kfei/gitlab-auditor#apply-patches-to-gitlab-services) project on **Github** and even use it to help you visualize  all these logs.